# How chain Retrofit calls?

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit, rx-java, observable

How can I make one retrofit 2 call after another?

I'm reading about RxJava and I'm already doing my calls using RxJava, but I havn't found a good exemple of how to use flatMaps.

Can someone explain how to do it to me?

I'm trying to make these two calls, and after they're both done, I want to start a new activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/")
            .build();

    WeatherService weatherService = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
    final Observable<Weather> london = weatherService.getCurrent();

    london.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Weather>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Weather weather) {

                    Log.i("WEATHER","Weather Name: " + weather.getName());


                }
            });

    final Observable<Wind> windObservable = weatherService.getWind();
    windObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Wind>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Wind wind) {

                  Log.i("WEATHER","Wind: " + wind.getSpeed().toString());  

                }
            });

}


}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to chain them in this case?  It might be more prudent to use `Observable.combineLatest()` to run these concurrently.  You would really only want to chain observables with maps if the next call depends on output from the previous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this link: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-observables will help. Checkout for zip. Eventually  switchMap method may be useful in Your case.

Edit:
Maybe this example http://joluet.github.io/blog/2014/07/07/rxjava-retrofit/ will help You even more.

Edit #2: Some code

```
login().switchMap(new Func1<FirstResponse, Observable<SecondResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<SecondResponse> call(FirstResponse t) {
                if (ApiUtils.isLoginValid(t)) {
                        return profile(t.getToken());
                    }
                    else{
                        return Observable.error(new CustomException());
                    }
                }

            }
        }).subscribe(subscriber());
```

Note: profile method return type is is `Observable<SecondResponse>` and subscriber method type is `Subscriber<? super SecondResponse>`

Comment: I've tried to follow the example, but I didn't get it, how do I set the second call to happen after the first? And do I need to set the calls using a normal Observable and then call them in the flatMap?

Comment: Just use switchMap then. From first observable create switchMap to "observable of second retrofit call". I made something like this few days ago and it worked like a charm.

Comment: How do I make this? I'm very new to RxJava and I know basically nothing, a code sample would be hugely helpful.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10869476)

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya & for dovnwoter I was going to update my answer with code when I get back from work.

Comment: @Axxxon I did not do downvoting I have just marked your answer as link only answer.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya I noted this :)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `flatMap` as in the example or `concatWith`:

```
static Observable<Integer> intObservable() {
    return Observable.just(1).delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

static Observable<String> stringObservable() {
    return Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).take(2).map(v -> v.toString());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    intObservable()
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .ignoreElements()
        .cast(Object.class)
    .concatWith(stringObservable()
            .doOnNext(System.out::println)
            .ignoreElements())
    .toBlocking()
    .subscribe();
}
```

However, you need some cast in case the two sources have different types.

Comment: I've added some code with the two calls I'm trying to do, so I need to create a new observable like intObservable() in your example and call the second Observable, in my case windObservable() in .concatWith()?

And one more question, using concatWith, there is a limit of how many calls I can make, after each other?

Comment: you can use `london` instead of `intObservable` and `wind`instead of `stringObservable` in my example

Comment: So I wont need the part of the code where I set onCompleted(), onError(), onNext(), .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) ? 

The .doOnNext is where I wold put the  Log.i("WEATHER","Weather Name: " + weather.getName());
for example?

Comment: Replace `System.out::println` with your side-effecting code as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here. One of them is to use `zip`:

```
london.zipWith(weatherService, new Func2<Weather, Wind, Something>() {
    @Override
    public Something call(final Weather weather, final Wind wind) {
        ...
        return something;
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Something>() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(final Throwable e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(final Something something) {

    }
});
```