# Retrofit Equeue Multiple RecyclerViews

Tags: java, android

I am using retrofit2 to enqueue multiple recyclerviews. It works great on one recyclerview but when i go to enqueue a second one with a different category it doesnt work.

I have tried making a second onresponse method, i cant think of any other way of doing it

```
Call<MovieResponse> call = apiInterface.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);//This one is working!

Call<MovieResponse> call1 = apiInterface.getNowPlayingMovies(API_KEY); //This is what i what to implement
```

Here is the code

```
Call<MovieResponse> call = apiInterface.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);

call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                int statuscode =response.code();
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.movie_item, getContext()));

                recyclerView1.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.movie_item, getContext())); //this works but not with the NowPlayingMovies, tested to see if it was the other recyclerview

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: You need to chain the requests call success-> call1 -> success then initialize both recyclerview's adapters or initialize on each successs. I think this will be useful for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34750719/how-chain-retrofit-calls

Comment: thank you!! i dont know how i missed that lol

Comment: `it doesnt work.` how exactly?

Comment: It didnt appear but i managed to chain the requests and fixed it

Answer (score 0):

If you dont prefer to use RxJava then you can use following solution:

```
Call<MovieResponse> call = apiInterface.getTopRatedMovies(API_KEY);

call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                int statuscode =response.code();
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();

                recyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.movie_item, getContext()));
                secondAPICall();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

public void secondAPICall(){
            call1.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<MovieResponse> call, Response<MovieResponse> response) {
                int statuscode =response.code();
                List<Movie> movies = response.body().getResults();

                recyclerView1.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(movies, R.layout.movie_item, getContext()));



            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<MovieResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```